# How to trigger fragment's onCreate method?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, fragment, oncreate

I have a `ViewPager` with 4 views. View #3 needs to respond to some broadcasted events. Hence, I register a custom `BroadcastReceiver` in `onCreate` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805269/programmatically-register-a-broadcast-receiver). This works if I make sure to show view #3, triggering the `onCreate` event. Otherwise, it doesn't work, obviously.

How can I make sure that `onCreate` is indeed called for fragments waiting to be shown. I.e. How to force fragment *creation*?

Comment: Solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348707/prevent-viewpager-from-destroying-off-screen-views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment above. `setOffscreenPageLimit` is the key.